# Allow voting on / dismissing job suggestions?

Tags: feature-request, voting, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, user-experience

E.g. I know for a fact that I will not apply to certain companies yet they are being shown again and again (small but prominent right-side banner). The service would work better both ways if there was a way of giving an instant feedback.

Comment: Yesyesyes! I'd love that. I've been annoyed by that for months. The same company (which I'd never apply to) filling up several spaces in the side bar all the time. I'd love to have a way to say "don't show me this job again".

Answer (score 4):

This request: I like it, it's a direct way to solve the problem of "I don't like this job" in my ad for engaged users.

Bigger Picture: You and HenningJ both brought up the problem of Freshness in job ads. We keep showing you the same jobs even though you don't click them. The Data Science team has been interested in solving that problem for everyone, even people who won't click the vote button next to the job in the ad, were we to provide it. We've done some analyses that show if you haven't interacted with a particular job we've chosen for you by something like it's 10th impression, you're probably not gonna and we should show you something else. We've got a couple experiments done, but the problem hasn't fallen yet. We are still working on it.

Comment: The non-job ads have voting buttons.

Comment: @Den: They do, but we (Stack Overflow) have no way to make those ads smarter, they're a packaged service to us. With job ads, we do have a way (we're in complete control of them).